# How can i setContentView in RelativeLayout? (progressbar)

Tags: android, progress-bar, nullpointerexception

can someone please explain to me how i can so setContentView in a relative layout?
i added an activity but i'm getting errors, nullpointers...

i tried this:

```
         public ProgressbarActivity(Context context) {
    super(context);

    Activity a = new Activity();
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
    LinearLayout k = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    k.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    LinearLayout z = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    z.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    RoundRectShape s = new RoundRectShape(f, null, null);
    ShapeDrawable shapedrawable =  new ShapeDrawable(s);
    shapedrawable.setShape(s);
    shapedrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xffffffff);


    RoundRectShape s1 = new RoundRectShape(f, null, null);
    ShapeDrawable sd =  new ShapeDrawable(s1);
    sd.setShape(s1);
    sd.getPaint().setColor(0xff0080ff);
    rl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(200, 25));

    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(200, 20);
    rl.setPadding(0, 100, 0, 0);
    rl.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


    ImageView iv = new ImageView(getContext());
    iv.setBackgroundDrawable(shapedrawable);
    iv.setLayoutParams(lp);


    GradientDrawable g = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colours);


    ImageView iv3 = new ImageView(getContext());
    iv3.setBackgroundDrawable(g);
    iv3.setLayoutParams(lp);

    ClipDrawable cd = new ClipDrawable(sd, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
    ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(getContext());
    iv2.setBackgroundDrawable(cd);
    iv2.setLayoutParams(lp);
    cd.setLevel(5000);


    rl.addView(iv);
    rl.addView(iv2);
    rl.addView(iv3);
    a.setContentView(rl);

    onCreate();

}
```

what did i do wrong?
can someone please explain it?

I'm getting a nullPointerException...

this is my logCat:

```
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eng.pim.app/eng.pim.app.PimActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1855)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at eng.pim.app.ProgressbarActivity.<init>(ProgressbarActivity.java:77)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at eng.pim.app.PimActivity.onCreate(PimActivity.java:24)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-30 06:58:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1534):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your logcat please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your code:

1) If `ProgressbarActivity` is an `Activity` you **don't** use the constructor for initialization, you **must** use the `onCreate()` method to initialize views, build data, setup threads etc.

2) You never do this:

```
Activity a = new Activity();
```

if you want to start a new activity with your layout that you build then you must use an `Intent` to start the new activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, OtherActivityName.class);
startActivity(i);
```

The above code will work in an activity, otherwise instead of `CurrentActivityName.this` you'll have to get a reference to some `Context`(you could use the application context with the method `getApplicationContext()`) and also you must call `startActivity()` on that `Context` reference. If you want the new activity to have the layout that you build then move that code in the new activity `onCreate()` method, use `setContentView()` there with the `Relativelayout` that you built and use the above code with the `Intent` to start that activity. (Note: you must declare the new activity in the manifest)

3) `RelativeLayout` stacks views(one on top of the others), if this isn't what you want then use rules to correctly position the views in that layout

Maybe you should see some tutorials on how to do it:

-- for `Activity` creation and starting one: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

-for `RelativeLayout` use: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html

Comment: thank you, that helped me a lot! :D also i'm just 14 years old :P

Comment: @user1297720 Read carefully the links I gave to learn about activities in android.